# What's the differences between patch and replace the deployment in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to update the image for the k8s deployment and I found two RESTAPI in k8s to update the deployment: `PATCH` and `PUT`.
I found out, that the `PATCH` is for updating and the `PUT` is for replacing in the official document but after testing with the two command:

```
kubectl patch -p ...
kubectl replace -f ...
```

it seems to has no differences between the two method.

Both of them can rollback and name of the new pod changed.

I wondered if it is only different in the request body for this two commands? (patch only need the changed part and put need the whole parts)

Answer (score 3):

According to the documenation:

`kubectl patch`

is to change the live configuration of a Deployment object. You do not change the configuration file that you originally used to create the Deployment object.

```
kubectl replace
```

If replacing an existing resource, the complete resource spec must be provided.

Answer (score 2):

`replace` is a full replacement.  You have to have ALL the fields present. 
`patch` is partial.

Comment: the op is asking for **replace**, why you say **PUT**?